# How to select a tube?

Tags: tire, valves

Hi I got a used bike and my experience with bikes is very limited. The tires and tubes are all broken so I need to get new ones. I found these tires: http://www.fahrrad.de/continental-speed-king-set-26-zoll-draht-362100.html

and I found these tubes for the tires: http://www.fahrrad.de/fahrradteile/reifen-schlaeuche/rcp-fahrradschlauch-26-zoll-universal/285443.html?eqrecqid=be78e9d1-f097-11e3-804f-c8600056a33a

but when I select the tubes the website asks me for the kind of valves I need. How to select that? Should I select the valves according to a criteria or should I get any valves?

Comment: Look at: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index-a-list-of-bike-part-names-and-cycling-concepts/284#284
And determine which valves your old tubes had.

Comment: You might be better off taking your old tire and tube to a bike shop, to buy replacements.  The salesperson at the shop can explain the important aspects of tire/tube size.

Answer (score 4):

Some rims have a small-diameter drilling for presta valves, so a schraeder (car-type) valve won't fit.

If your rim is drilled for schraeder valves, you can use presta valves, but you should use a plastic adapter sleeve to hold the valve in position and avoid wear to the valve stem or the edge of the drilling.

Comment: I will order a DV valve, is that ok?

Comment: DV is Dunlop (or Woods) valve. These are not a popular choice nowadays. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valve_stem for images of the three kinds.

Comment: +1 for a nice, compact, accurate answer. Just to say that I bought a new bike just last year (a Dutch sit-up-and-beg) which came with Woods valves. First time I'd seen them in 30 years but there is obviously a small following out there.